# Django Rest Frame Work: passing User in djago rest frame work

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project as following code in model

```
class Report(models.Model):
    created_by_user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

following code in serializer

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Report
        fields='__all__'
```

and following code in view

```
class ReportCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        received_data=ReportSerializer(data=request.data)
        if received_data.is_valid():
            received_data.save()
            return Response(received_data.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(received_data.errors,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when I send a post request by postman and send username and password in Authorization tab
it error:

```
{
    "created_by_user": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

but if I type username or password incorrect it will be

```
{
    "detail": "Invalid username/password."
}
```

can everybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your serializer has no idea about the currently logged-in user.You to pass it as context from `request. user` or request.

I personally prefer `CurrentUserDefault` to be used in the serializer. To make it work we need to pass the request as context because `CurrentUserDefault` picks user from context request. We need to update our views and serializer code as follows

Views file: Add request as context context

```
class ReportCreateView(APIView):


def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    received_data=ReportSerializer(data=request.data, context = {"request": request})
    if received_data.is_valid():
        received_data.save()
        return Response(received_data.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(received_data.errors,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py: Update your serializer to auto-populate `created_by_user`

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_by_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    
    class Meta:
        model=Report
        fields='__all__'
```

It will solve your user field required issue.

```
"created_by_user": ["This field is required."]
```

Now coming to your next part of the issue that is related to incorrect passwords.

By default, `APIView` picks the default authentication class from settings. Inside projects `settings.py`, we mostly write these lines while using DRF and they serve as default authentication for APIView:

From settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ],
    # Authentication settings
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
   ...
}
```

Inside APIView you can have a look at default `permission_classes`, and `authentication_classes`

From inside APIView:

```
    authentication_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES
    throttle_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES
    permission_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES
```

that is when you type an invalid password:

```
"detail": "Invalid username/password."
```

Provide the correct username and password to your APIView from postman so that it gets the requested logged-in user for auto-populates at DB level.

Comment: what is it? serializers.HiddenField

Comment: `serializers.HiddenField` is used when you do not to expose it for both reading and writing. So it can be used where we have to fil default values only for internal usage Not for exposing it to API Level.

Answer (score 1):

you don't perform any process on your user data and just need to save the request user, due to that I think you don't need a serializer field for it and it's better to get your current user in view. also if you need more fields to serialize, you can make created_by_user read_only true and set its value on your view.

for example, if you have report name and report desc field in your model:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    created_by_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

perform your serializer like this :

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'created_by_user': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

then set created_by_user value in your view:

```
class ReportCreateView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['created_by_user'] = request.user # just need add this line 
        received_data = ReportSerializer(data=request.data)
        if received_data.is_valid():
            received_data.save()
            return Response(received_data.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(received_data.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```